# Exporting a manipulate function as a .gif

Tags: plotting, manipulate, export, code-request, gif-format

How can I export this code:

```
Manipulate[Plot[a*Cos[2 Pi*x]*Exp[-(10^2)/x^2], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 1, 10}]
```

As a .gif that walks trough the values for $a$?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
pe = Flatten@
       Table[Manipulate[
         Plot[a*Cos[2 Pi*x]*Exp[-(10^2)/x^2], {x, 0, 10}], {{a, m1}, 1, 
          10}], {m1, 1, 10}];

Export["C:/tcdata/file.gif", pe]
```

Comment: And how can I export it to a .avi video format with high quality?

Comment: @Looper `Export["C:/tcdata/file.avi", pe]`

Comment: @Looper type "avi" + hit F1. And so on.